# my C program to find factorial is not giving me my desired result

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int n, f = 1;
    printf("enter any number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n > 0) {
        f = f * n;
        n = n - 1;
    }
    printf("factorial of %d is %d", n, f);
}
```

And it gives me a result:

```
enter any number: 5
factorial of 0 is 120
```

Comment: `n` is going down to zero in your program. So no wonder zero is printed.

Comment: You're essentially printing your counter, instead of printing a variable for what you read (since you modified that into nonexistence). Make a copy variable or print incrementally

Comment: You *must* always check the value returned by scanf, even in trivial cases like this.  This program exhibits undefined behavior on input "foo".

Comment: You may not want to print 1 when the user enters a negative number.

Answer (score 4):

Just save the original input:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n,n1,f=1;
    printf("enter any number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    n = n1;
    while(n>0)
    {
        f=f*n;
        n=n-1;
    }
    printf("factorial of %d is %d",n1,f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to use a for loop for this. It lets you declare a local variable for the loop which you can initialise to `n` without affecting the value of `n`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, f=1;

    printf("enter any number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (int i=n; i>0; i--)
        f *= i;

    printf("factorial of %d is %d\n", n, f);
}
```

Comment: I did it successfully with for loop already but I want to do it with the while loop

Answer (score 1):

C has syntax which lets you define a new variable for your loop, which will be gone after your loop finishes. This lets you run a loop without changing user input inside the loop.

```
scanf("%d",&n);
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
{
    f=f*i;
}
```

Some people like `for` loops more than `while` loops, because they have more "structure" - all code related to loop organization is in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is " n=n-1;" because of this line the n value is becoming zero at the end so save the n value in some variable and then print in the last

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int n,f=1, k;
printf("enter any number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
k=n;// do this
while(n>0)
{
    f=f*n;
    n=n-1;
}
printf("factorial of %d is %d",k,f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the value of `n` after the loop, you should not modify `n` in the `while` loop, but use a temporary variable `i` to enumerate the factors.

Also note that `main()` has a return type of `int` and return `0` on successful exit.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, f = 1;
    printf("enter any number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        int i = n;
        while (i > 1) {
            f = f * i;
            i = i - 1;
        }
        printf("factorial of %d is %d", n, f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

n will always be 0 at the end of while loop. You can't print the old value if you use n as a counter. Make a separate variable and use it as a counter in your while loop.